# Does the Math-tea Argument Have Any Relevance to the Method of Forcing?

Tags: set-theory, forcing

The Math-tea Argument (i.e. the argument that, for example, there must be real numbers that we cannot describe or define, because there are only countably many definitions, but uncountably many reals) pops up in some very interesting places.  Consider the following statement from Prof. Alexandre Miquel of the Universidad De La Republica, Uruguay, found in his course notes titled "An axiomatic presentation of the method of forcing" under the subheading "The fundamental under-specification of the powerset" (the reader can find these course notes under title on the Web):

"The reader might wonder how it is possible to add new subsets to already existing infinite sets, and in particular to the set $\omega$ of natural numbers.  Mathematicians are so used to manipulate subsets of $\omega$ (or real numbers) that they often develop the (wrong) intuition that all these subsets are given a priori.

But one should remember that the language we use to define subsets of $\omega$ is (intuitively) denumerable, so that the (intuitive) collection formed by all the subsets of $\omega$ that we can individually define is denumerable.  The vast majority of the subsets of $\omega$, that only exist via Cantor's diagonal argument, are definitely out of reach by linguistic means--at least individually--and their existence is, in some sense, purely formal.   The method of forcing precisely exploits this fundamental under-specification of the powerset (of infinite sets) by specifying extra subsets by extra linguistic means...."

Is this statement by Prof. Miquel correct, and if not, why not, given the results of Hamkins, Linetsky, and Reitz?

Comment: What results are you referring to?

Comment: Just as reference for the readers, the name is [definable number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definable_real_number). And even those are arguable not "the ones with content", but rather their subset called [computable numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number).

Comment: The results in their paper "Pointwise Definable Models Of Set Theory".  Look on www.boolesrings.org for the paper.

Comment: @Danul:  Also on arXiv (look under title) .  The specific theorem I am referring to is their theorem "Every countable model of ZFC has a pointwise definable class forcing extension", i.e. a class forcing extension M[G] where every element of M[G] is definable in M[G] without parameters.  "In such models [I am quoting directly from their paper--my comment], all objects are discernible; every object satisfies a unique principle complete 1-type." For a nice sketch of the proof, see Miha's answer to my Math Stack Exchange question "Some Questions Regarding Pointwise Definable Models of ZFC."

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I will look in to it.

Comment: Also, for the sake of completeness, an element 'a' of a structure $\mathcal M$ is definable (without parameters) when there is a formula $\phi$(x) in the language of $\mathcal M$ such that $\mathcal M$ $\vDash$ $\phi$[x] only at x=a.

Comment: Err, I might be missing something, but if $M$ is a ctm, I'm guessing $M[G]$ is a ctm and then everything in $M[G]$ being definable in $M[G]$ doesn't really contradict anything that is being said, since all you are doing is using countably many formulas. It sounds like $M[G]$ is a specific extension of $M$ that is the atomic model of its own theory. So if I'm not mistaken, $M[G]$ is a prime model of its own theory.

Comment: @DanulG:  M[G] being a pointwise definable model of ZFC is equivalent to saying that M[G] is a prime model of ZFC+(V=HOD).  That is part of Observation 5 of their paper found on pg 4 of the arXiv preprint so in that sense you are correct.  Also, Hamkins, Linetsky, and Reitz make the following statement on pg. 4 of the arXiv preprint:  "Clearly, pointwise definable models in a countable language must be countable, since there are only countably many definitions."  I find that very interesting....

Comment: @DanulG:  What is the chance of having the authors redoing the forcing arguments in their paper using boolean-valued models.  Could this in fact be done?

Comment: Highly unlikely, I would think. I'm not a set theorist, so I'm not sure. But the accepted wisdom is you can always convert between the two, allowing for obvious modifications. Here I think you'd just have to say $M$ is a ctm to begin with and not some arbitrary transitive model of $ZFC$. But as I said, I'm not a set theorist.

Comment: But I haven't seen the paper so I don't know if they use very esoteric arguments that would make the process extremely difficult.

Comment: Anyhow, addressing your original question, I think the "math tea" intuition still holds, seeing as $M[G]$ is countable and hence you are do not really have access to any weird subset of $\omega$ in any "explicit manner".